# print number in horizontally and reverse order and show on label in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to print the numbers in the horizontal and then show in reverse order, now, in the following code below, the logic is correct and show the number on the console, imrpimi okay, as shown in the second link and show these same values in a label in JavaFX, shows the opposite of the desired solution

```
public class GridPane extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    for (int number = 8; number > 0; number--) {
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
      str.append(number);
      Label label = new Label(str.toString());
      System.out.println(str.toString());
      label.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));
      label.setPrefSize(20, 20);
      root.add(label,0, number + 3);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 900);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Grid Pane Example");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
```

to test the program, I got is output https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeFyL.jpg

the goal is to follow this logic in which the console displays the result correctly like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/77JY7.jpg

Any suggestions, I appreciate and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters to `root.add(...)` are the node you are adding, the column index, and the row index. So you are always adding the label displaying `number` in row `number + 3`: i.e. `8` goes in row 11, `7` goes in row 10, etc.

The order of iteration makes no difference.

If you want `1` in row 11, `2` in row 10, `3` in row 9, etc, then you would have to notice that `rowIndex = 12 - number` and call

```
root.add(label, 0, 12 - number);
```